# How to add small text inside an input-group?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a small text inside an input-group like in this picture.

[image: here]

How I can achieve this?

```
<div class="input-group">
   <select class="form-select  p-2" style="border-radius: 8px;">
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Department</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</option>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Select options do not have `href` attributes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attributes. A div is not a valid child of a select element. You may be confusing Bootstrap's [dropdown dividers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#dividers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image I see a floating label in a select input as [in bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/#selects)

To do this I modified your code:

```css
/* Perzonalize it */

.form-floating>.form-select~label::after {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group form-floating">
  <select class="form-select  p-2" id="floatingSelect" style="border-radius: 8px;">
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Department</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</option>
    <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="floatingSelect" style="background-color: transparent;">Select anythink</label>
</div>
```

The little text on select is in the label: `<label for="floatingSelect" style="background-color: transparent;">Select anythink</label>`